# Performance of Dictionary<string, object> vs List<string> + BinarySearch

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I have a custom performance timer implementation. In short it is a static data collection storing execution duration of some code paths. In order to identify particular measurements I need a collection of named objects with quick access to the data item by name i.e. a `string` of moderate length like 20-50 chars.

Straightforward way to do that could be a `Dictionary<string, MyPerformanceCounter>` with access by key which is the counter id.

What about a `List<MyPerformanceCounter>` which could be accessed and maintained sorted via `List<T>.BinarySearch` and `List.Insert`. Does it have a chance to have more linear performance when I would need to have several hundreds of counters?

Needless to say I need the access to the proper `MyPerformanceCounter` to be as quick as possible as it is called at rates of dozens of thousands per second and should affect code execution as less as possible.

New counters are appended relatively seldom like once per second.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @Blorgbeard I get the idea of this remark. The problem is I do not know how to correctly measure the difference in performance of the two. I was hoping for some hint based on in-depth knowledge of internals under the hood as long as these API groups are ancient and could already get explored deeply by somebody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several potentially non-O(1) parts to a dictionary.

The first is generating a hash code.  If your strings are long, it will have to generate a hash of the string every time you use it as a key in your dictionary.  The dictionary stores the hashes of the existing keys, so you don't have to worry about that, just hashing what you're passing in.  If the strings are all short, hashing should be fast.  Long strings are probably going to take longer to hash than doing a string comparison.  Hashing affects both reads and writes.

The next non-constant part of a dictionary is when you have hash collisions.  It keeps a linked list of values with the same hash bucket internally, and has to go through and compare your key to each item in that bucket if you get hash collisions.  Since you're using strings and they spent a lot of effort coming up with a good string hashing function, this shouldn't be too major an issue.  Hash collisions slow down both reads and writes.

The last non-constant part is only during writes, if it runs out of internal storage, it has to recalculate the whole hash table internally.  This is still a lot faster than doing array inserts (like a List<> would do).  If you only have a few hundred items, this is definitely not going to affect you.

A list, on the other hand, is going to take an average of N/2 copies for each insert, and log2(N) for each lookup.  Unless the strings all have similar prefixes, the individual comparisons will be much faster than the dictionary, but there will be a lot more of them.

So unless your strings are quite long to make hashing inefficient, chances are a dictionary is going to give you better performance.

If you know something about the nature of your strings, you can write a more specific data structure optimized for your scenario.  For example, if I knew all the strings started with an ASCII capital letter, and each is between 5 and 10 characters in length, I might create an array of 26 arrays, one for each letter, and then each of those arrays contains 6 lists, one for each length of string.  Something like this:

```
List<string>[][] lists = new List<string>[26][6];
foreach (string s in keys)
{
    var list = lists[s[0] - 'A'][s.Length - 5];
    if (list == null)
    {
        lists[s[0] - 'A'][s.Length] = list = new List<string>();
    }
    int ix = list.BinarySearch(s);
    if (ix < 0)
    {
        list.Insert(~ix, s);
    }
}
```

This is the kind of thing you do if you have very specific information about what kind of data you're dealing with.  If you can't make assumptions, using a Dictionary is most likely going to be your best bet.

You might also want to consider using OrderedDictionary if you want to go binary search route, I believe it uses a binary search tree internally. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That's what I needed. Need time to think your data through in detail and `OrderedDictionary` in particular. I got the example with the restriction on the first letter as well. Will consider it i.e. to make it more versatile for the case of small but undefined number of different string prefixes. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use the `Dictionary<string, MyPerformanceCounter>`.

For small sets of data the list will have a better performance. However, as more elements are needed, the Dictionary becomes clearly superior.

- The time required for a `Dictionary` is:  *O(1)* **constant** time
  complexity.
- The List has an *O(N)* **linear** time complexity.

You could try `Hashtable` or `SortedDictionary`, but I think that you should still use `Dictionary`.

I provide a link with benchmarks and guidelines here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-time

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Did you notice me speaking of the BinarySearch for the List strategy? I do not plan to use List.Contains.